# run PHP include in a PHP echo

Tags: php, html, include, comments, echo

It sounds strange even for me but basically what i need is to include a php file inside an echo. Unfortunately i can't end the echo before include and continue it after that because all of that is part of an while statement.

And if if i do it like in the code below, in html that  is seen as a comment.

Hope you can help me figured it out.

```
<?php
include('connect.php');
$nrcrt=1;
$sql="SELECT Cod, Nume, Categorie, Tumb, Tabel, Descriere FROM produse";
$sqlcateg="SELECT categ FROM categorii";
$resultcateg=$conn->query($sqlcateg);
$result=$conn->query($sql);

if($result->num_rows>0)
{
    while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
        {   
            echo    '<tr>
                        <td>'.$nrcrt.'</td>
                        <td>'.$row['Cod'].'
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                function editcod'.$nrcrt.'() {
                                var x = document.getElementById("fieldscod'.$nrcrt.'");
                                if (x.style.display === "none") {   
                                    x.style.display = "block";
                                } else {
                                    x.style.display = "none";
                                }
                                };
                                </script>
                                <br> <br> 
                                <button onclick="editcod'.$nrcrt.'()">Editare</button>
                                <br>
                                <div id="fieldscod'.$nrcrt.'"hidden><input type="text" id="fieldupdatecod" value="'.$row['Cod'].'">
                                <br>
                                <input id="updatecod" type="submit" value="Update"></div>
                        </td>
                        <td>'.$row['Nume'].'
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                function editnume'.$nrcrt.'() {
                                var x = document.getElementById("fieldsnume'.$nrcrt.'");
                                if (x.style.display === "none") {   
                                    x.style.display = "block";
                                } else {
                                    x.style.display = "none";
                                }
                                };
                                </script>
                                <br> <br>
                                <button onclick="editnume'.$nrcrt.'()">Editare</button>
                                <br>
                                <div id="fieldsnume'.$nrcrt.'" hidden><input type="text" id="fieldupdatenume" value="'.$row['Nume'].'">
                                <br>
                                <input id="updatenume" type="submit" value="Update"></div>
                        </td>
```

Here will be the problem, inside this .

```
                            <td>'.$row['Categorie'].'
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                function editcateg'.$nrcrt.'() {
                                var x = document.getElementById("fieldscateg'.$nrcrt.'");
                                if (x.style.display === "none") {   
                                    x.style.display = "block";
                                } else {
                                    x.style.display = "none";
                                }
                                };
                                </script>
                                <br><br>
                                <button onclick="editcateg'.$nrcrt.'()">Editare</button>
                                <br>
                                <div id="fieldscateg'.$nrcrt.'" hidden>

                                <?php include("_include/php/readcateg.php");?>

                                <br>
                                <input id="updatecategorie" type="submit" value="Update"></div>
                        </td>
                        <td>'.$row['Descriere'].'
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                function editdesc'.$nrcrt.'() {
                                var x = document.getElementById("fieldsdesc'.$nrcrt.'");
                                if (x.style.display === "none") {   
                                    x.style.display = "block";
                                } else {
                                    x.style.display = "none";
                                }
                                };
                                </script>
                                <br>
                                <button onclick="editdesc'.$nrcrt.'()">Editare</button>
                                <br><br>
                                <br>
                                <div id="fieldsdesc'.$nrcrt.'" hidden><textarea rows="5" id="fieldupdatedescriere">'.$row['Descriere'].'</textarea>
                                <br>
                                <input id="updatedescriere" type="submit" value="Update"></div>
                        </td>
                        <td><img src="_include/hfs/tumb/'.$row['Tumb'].'">
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                function edittumb'.$nrcrt.'() {
                                var x = document.getElementById("fieldstumb'.$nrcrt.'");
                                if (x.style.display === "none") {   
                                    x.style.display = "block";
                                } else {
                                    x.style.display = "none";
                                }
                                };
                                </script>
                                <button onclick="edittumb'.$nrcrt.'()">Editare</button>
                                <br>
                                <div id="fieldstumb'.$nrcrt.'" hidden>
                                <input type="file" name="tumb" id="fileToUpload">
                                <input id="updatetumb" type="submit" value="Update"></div>
                        </td>
                        <td><img src="_include/hfs/tabel/'.$row['Tabel'].'">
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                function edittabel'.$nrcrt.'() {
                                var x = document.getElementById("fieldstabel'.$nrcrt.'");
                                if (x.style.display === "none") {   
                                    x.style.display = "block";
                                } else {
                                    x.style.display = "none";
                                }
                                };
                                </script>
                                <button onclick="edittabel'.$nrcrt.'()">Editare</button>
                                <br>
                                <div id="fieldstabel'.$nrcrt.'" hidden>
                                <input type="file" name="tabel" id="fileToUpload">
                                <input id="updatetabel" type="submit" value="Update"></div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="sterge" type="submit" value="Sterge">
                        </td>
                    </tr>';
            $nrcrt=$nrcrt+1;
        }
}
    else 
    { echo "0 results";}

?>
```

Comment: _"Unfortunately i can't end the echo before include and continue it after that"_ - but you can put it in a string var first, and echo that at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a full string text with php include and depended scripts as a string init then [eval](http://php.net/manual/de/function.eval.php) it.

For example:

```
 $str =    '
<div>
    <?php include("_include/php/readcateg.php");?>
    <?php  echo $var; ?>
</div>';
echo eval($str);
```

Comment: although this might work I'd not suggest to use `eval` anywhere.

Comment: Echoing html between php and use php between html is not recommended too :)

Comment: true that! (adding more words just to exceed the minimum for a comment...)

Comment: I tried to make it work your way, but it doesn't seem to work, maybe i'm doing something wrong because this is the error i get: 

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\HFS\_include\php\showdata.php(13) : eval()'d code on line 2

line 13 : echo eval($str);
line 2: include('connect.php');